# Rails daemon do not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I have Rails 3.0.3 project and I trying to create daemon by this steps:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon

I've installed gem daemons

> sudo gem install daemons

Then I've install daemon_generator

> rails plugin install https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator.git

Then created daemon

> rails generate daemon game_processor

When I try to run daemon

> ./lib/daemons/game_processor_ctl start

I got error:

> ./lib/daemons/game_processor_ctl:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
>   from ./lib/daemons/game_processor_ctl:2

Code of daemon:

> #!/usr/bin/env ruby
>
> require 'rubygems'
>
> require "daemons"
>
> require 'yaml'
>
> require 'erb'
>
> gem 'activesupport', '>=3.0.0.beta4'
>   require 'active_support'
>
> # For some reason, ActiveSupport 3.0.0 doesn't load.
>   # Load needed extension directly for now.
>   require "active_support/core_ext/object"
>   require "active_support/core_ext/hash"
>
> options = YAML.load(
>     ERB.new(
>       IO.read(
>         File.dirname(**FILE**) + "/../../config/daemons.yml"
>     )).result).with_indifferent_access
>
> options[:dir_mode] = options[:dir_mode].to_sym
>
> Daemons.run File.dirname(**FILE**) + "/game_processor.rb", options

So, What's wrong? Why it dies, when trying to require rubygems?

Comment: [disclosure: I'm the same person as hosts the daemon_generator repository]. It looks like the ruby described the first line of your daemon script is not the same as the one you are using generally. Do you have more than one Ruby installed? Using RVM?

Comment: I have 2 executables: ruby and ruby1.9, but I do not use ruby1.9. No RVM.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Although I'm using RVM. Infuriating!

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows or *nix system - on Windows you should use `ruby game_processor.rb start` instead of _ctl.

Also as you are using it with Rails - then i think Rails server should be started in required mode as well to make Daemon run properly.

Comment: I'm on Mac. Rails server started. When I try to comment some require-directives, ctl-file die with error "Unknown [some] symbol".